# Not getting the response after adding debug proxy

Tags: android

I have an android application where i connect to server and get the data to be rendered. To show the maps I added '**-http-proxy IP:port -debug-proxy**' to 'Additional emulator command line options' in eclipse . Since i have added this I am unable to recieve the response properly. 
I am using HTTP connection to connect to server and get the response. I am using following code :

```
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       Log.v("Response",""+response.toString());
       responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
       Log.v("ResponseBody",""+responseBody);
```

First Log statement is getting executed but second Log statement is not getting executed.

I am getting following in the console:

sent closed=0 data=0 n=0 ret=0

connection reset by peer (receive)

body completed by close (13908 bytes)

I am not getting complete response and connection is getting lost.

Everything is working fine fine if i remove '-http-proxy IP:port -debug-proxy' . But then i cant show map.

Pls help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Syntax: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: Yes I have added that. The problem is i am not getting complete response. Connection is getting timed out before complete response is recieved. But its working fine if i remove ' -http-proxy IP:port -debug-proxy'